# Android cold start How do I find what devices have issues

Tags: flutter, performance, google-play-console

I uploaded a Flutter app to Google Play Console for some external testers to try.

In the Google Play Console there's a section Pre-Launch Report. In this section's "Overview" there's a subsection called "Performance", in here there are two items:

> Cold start time
> Your app took 6,982ms to launch for the first time, after being installed on this device model

and

> Cold start time
> Your app took 8,250ms to launch for the first time, after being installed on this device model

It has an arrow next to both items implying you can find out what device model had these huge start up times.

However, all it does is take me to a list of models that **didn't** have issues. That's not very useful to anyone.

Is there a way to find out what models it has issues on?

[image: What I see when I look at this screen]

Comment: Any update on this?  For what it's worth, this happens with non-Flutter apps too.

Comment: @Bink sadly not... this has gone unresolved this whole time.

Answer (score -2):

Look closely and you will see the device:

[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show that that doesn't exist for me.